# Python with Sqlite3 Syntqx error doing a select query with where condition where parameter is a variable of type integer

Tags: sqlite, flask

What I want to do is to query Sqlite database based on where condition. Sqlite column that I want to search is 'index'. I want to query on parameter value that is integer and comes from POST response from HTML. My Python code as follows:

```
    @app.route('/get', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
    def getfmhtml():
    input = str()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input = int(request.form['input'])
        print(input)
        import sqlite3 as sql
        conn = sql.connect('tryme.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        # rows = c.execute("select * from tryme where index = ?", [input]).fetchall()
        sql = "select * from tryme where index = ?"
        rows = c.execute(sql, [input]).fetchall()
        return render_template('index.html', rows = rows)
```

Error I am getting is:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error
```

My sqlitetable view looks like:

[Sqlite table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfJWx.png)

Comment: `index` is a reserved word.

Comment: thank you @forpas. I added a new column to DB and changed query to this column instead of index, and it worked.